# Finding Current in Parallel RLC Circuit with 2 voltage sources?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, circuit-analysis, inductor

I've spent sometime learning about step responses for series/parallel RLC circuits, but this problem takes things a step further, since C seems to be in parallel with a series combination of RL and a voltage source. I'm trying to find out what **i(t)** is for t≥0, since the switch has been closed for a long time before opening at t =0. 
[image]
My understanding is that for the step response, the solution calls for a second-order differential equation that takes into account both the forced response and the function for natural response. So when I focused on the t=0- condition, I set the inductor as a short circuit and the capacitor as a open circuit. From there, I also set i(t=0-) = i_L(t=0-). I used KVL to solve for i_L(t=0-):

i_L(t=0-) = (20V + 10V)/(5Ω + 5Ω) = 3 A = i_L(t=0+) <-- (I believe this is the initial current across inductor and R2?)

As for finding v_c(0-), I did a voltage divider to end up with:
v_c(0-) = (5Ω)/(5Ω + 5Ω) = 5V = v_c(0+) <-- (I'm assuming this is the initial voltage of capacitor?)
[image]
Now what I don't completely understand is the t≥0 condition. With the switch open, the left side of the circuit is ignored, leaving only the right side of the RLC circuit as the circuit reaches steady state. The problem is:

- From the way I modified the circuit, it seems to represent a **series** RLC circuit. Which would lead to the neper frequency (α = (R/2L) = 5 and resonant radian frequency, ω = (1/sqrt(LC)) = 5, leading to a critically damped response. From here, the general solution of the step response for series RLC circuit is:
  x(t) = Xf + D'1te^-at + D'2e^-at, with x either being v or i, and "Xf" being either the final voltage or final current
- At t=∞, it's readily known that capacitor acts as a open circuit again, and the inductor as a short circuit, and because V2 is included in the reduced circuit, my understanding is that the final voltage, or v_c(t=∞), is 10V, and that the *final current across R2 is ~ 0 A* at the steady state. I even verified this with the use of the Falstad online circuit simulator shown below:
  [image]

I am quite lost on this issue on finding **i(t)**. What I do know is that I am dealing with a series RLC circuit for t≥0, and that the general solution for i(t) takes the form of:

iL(t) = I_f + D'1*t*e^(-at) + D'2*e^(-at).

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to solve for **i(t)** for t≥0?

Comment: When the switch is opened it's a series circuit because the same current flows through each component.You will then need to derive and solve a 2nd order differential equation or analyse via Laplace transform.

Comment: @Chu So my suspicions were correct then. So, in regards to deriving and solving the 2nd-order diff. equation, would I just need to sum up the voltages around the closed path (when switch is open), and then differentiate with respect to time? I'd like to try to Laplace transform but my class never really had the opportunity to utilize that approach, but I'd like to know about that too.

Comment: Yes, use \$v_L=L\frac{di_L}{dt}\$ and, \$ v_C=\frac{1}{C}\int{i_C \: dt}\$, and then differentiate the KVL equation to get rid of the integral term. Don't forget to include the initial conditions on the capacitor and inductor.

Comment: @Chu Hmm, so for the initial conditions of both the inductor and capacitor, I calculated those values, but I'm not seeing how they play a role in solving the 2nd ODE. How exactly do those come into play?

Comment: @Chu Forgive me for asking this as well, but since the single loop involves a single current, can't we just idenitfy i_L = i_c, since they run along the same direction? Or am I wrong to assume this?

Comment: You are correct. In a series circuit the same current flows through each and every component. Of course, the voltages across each component may differ. In a parallel configuration the opposite is true - each component has the same voltage across; but different currents through.

Comment: ... When deriving the differential equation it's important to get the correct signs for the voltages across each component. For example, if your assumed current direction (which may be arbitrary, but which cannot change once nominated) is, say,from A to B through an inductor, then the induced back emf MUST be '+' on the A terminal and '-' on the B terminal. That is, the induced voltage acts in opposition to the current flow.

Comment: @Chu Yes, and that's exactly the issue I encountered here for the components with respect to sign convention. From my understanding, at t= infinity, voltage from V2 only remains between that and the cap such that the final voltage reaches the capacitor at 10V But the capacitor is unpolarized, so I'm unsure what exactly is the sign convention for that component. The same goes for the inductor as well. I did a counterclockwise loop around the reduced circuit, to follow the direction of the V2 source and i(t). But how do I know if I'm setting the correct signs for each component?

Comment: Taking the current at \$t=0^+ \$ as \$i(t)=i\$, as shown in your diagram, then KVL gives \$10+5-L\frac{di}{dt}=\frac{1}{C}\int{i\:dt}+Ri\$. Now differentiate to give: \$L\frac{d^2i}{dt^2}+R\frac{di}{dt}+\frac{i}{C}=0\$, where \$R=R_2+R_3=10\$. And solve, taking the initial condition, \$i(0)=3\$.

Comment: @Chu Hmm, okay I think I can see how you set up your KVL equation: turn out that I had used the wrong sign conventions when setting it up. So that initial condition does actually match to one of the arbitrary coefficients needed to solve for i(t), but what I am confused about is that diL(0+)/dt is also another initial condition associated with the differential equation. I found D2 = 3, which led to my current equation as i(t) = D1*t*e^(-5t) + 3e^(-5t). Now I know that by differentiating this, I can identify diL(0+)/dt, but that can also be found from the circuit too, right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Chu  Also, I just discovered something important about the final current of the diagram for t = 0+: if I do a source transformation on the 10V source with the 10 ohm equivalent resistance, that leads to a current source = 1 A, which would be I_f. I presume this would be also correct too?

Comment: No, that can't be correct; the final current is zero.

Comment: ... on your previous question, yes - the system has repeated roots at \$s=-5\$, therefore the solution is of the form: \$(ct+k)e^{-5t}\$

Comment: @Chu Yes, that's the correct solution form of the equation, and I finally solved for the answer of that form. Thank you very much for all the clarification you've provided!